# ggplot() + geom_text_wordcloud() - The text is overlapped in the Rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqPYE.png):"In the Rstudio"

ggplot() + geom_text_wordcloud()

```
topterm %>% group_by(topic_name) %>%
  ggplot(aes(label = word, size = n,
             color = factor(n))) +
  facet_wrap(~ topic_name, scales = "free", ncol = 2) +
  geom_text_wordcloud(seed = 1234, family = "nanumgothic") +
  geom_text_wordcloud_area(rm_outside = TRUE) +
  scale_radius(limits = c(20, NA), range = c(3, 15)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

The text is overlapped in the "Rstudio".

(This situation occurs when proceed with a multi-mediated word cloud, not a single word cloud.)

Even if I press the "Export" button on the word cloud, there are overlapped.

Therefore, there are many cases where you press the "Zoom" button to check the word cloud.

It doesn't matter if I'm the only one uncomfortable when I check the results of WordCloud...

Even when I use "R markdown" to save it as html, it's a problem because the situation occurs in WordCloud.

(1) Is there a way to output text in the "R studio" word cloud so that it doesn't overlap?

(2) Is there a way to save text without overlapping in "R markdown" wordcloud?

Comment: hi say_myname! please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)